# How would I write this in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to search the MySQL database comparing a column list to an array. How would I do this, possibly all within MySQL?

Here's what I want to do in PHP:

```
<?php
$array = array("a", "b", "c", "d");
// 'c' doesn't exist in the database
$result = $this->mysqli->query("Query");
// Result should be array("a", "b", "d")
?>
```

How would I do this?

Comment: This kind of thing can be crazy easy with a framework or ORM. Any reason you're doing it the hard way by using `mysqli` directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with [the IN clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in).

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE <col> IN <array>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// The array
$array = array("a", "b", "c", "d");

// This takes the array and puts it into a string like "a,b,c,d"
$array_for_query = implode(',', $array);

$result = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE the_letter IN ({$array_for_query})");
```

Replace `table` and `the_letter` with your table and column name respectively.

Comment: Don't forget that you can't trust user data in queries. If you're ever using an array of data gathered from the user, be sure to escape it with mysqli_real_escape_string before padding the data directly into the query. This prevents SQL injection attacks.